# Validation using Yup with key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

So I'm trying to validate my form using the Yup package, there is a function `createForm` to create a form which creates a form with unique ID, and then  that ID is pass to fields for every form which is created. I'm trying to validate those fields for each form created but I'm failing to validate those inputs with the unique id present. Here is the code :

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

const AddContact = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState([{key: nanoid()}])

    const createForm = () => {
      setFormData(prevFormData => [...prevFormData, {key: nanoid()}])
    }

   const deleteForm = (key) => {
      setFormData(prevFormData => prevFormData.filter(item => item.key !== key))
    }

return(
<Formik
      initialValues={{}}
      validationSchema={
      formData.map(data => {
         Yup.object().shape({
           [`name_${data.key}`]: Yup.string().required("Please enter a valid name"),
           [`company_${data.key}`]: Yup.string().required("Please enter a Company name"),
           [`mobile_no_${data.key}`]: Yup.number().typeError("Please enter a valid mobile number"),
           [`email_${data.key}`]: Yup.string().email().required("Please enter a valid email"),
         })
       })
     }
       //onSubmit={onSubmit}
>
 {({ handleSubmit, values }) => {
       return(
            <div>
              {formData.map((data, index) => {
               return(
               <button onClick={() => deleteForm(data.key)}}>
               <input name={`name_${data.key}`}>
               <input name={`company_${data.key}`}>
               <input name={`mobile_no_${data.key}`}>
               <input name={`email_${data.key}`}>
              )})}
              <button onClick={createForm}/>
            </div>
     )
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
I have created validationSchema from formData and it is working fine as it shows `errors` and `values` at the bottom of the form right now.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const AddContact = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState([{ key: nanoid() }]);

  const createForm = () => {
    setFormData((prevFormData) => [...prevFormData, { key: nanoid() }]);
  };

  const deleteForm = (key) => {
    setFormData((prevFormData) =>
      prevFormData.filter((item) => item.key !== key)
    );
  };

  const validationSchema = {
    ...formData.reduce((result, data) => {
      result = {
        ...result,
        [`name_${data.key}`]: Yup.string().required(
          "Please enter a valid name"
        ),
        [`company_${data.key}`]: Yup.string().required(
          "Please enter a Company name"
        ),
        [`mobile_no_${data.key}`]: Yup.number().typeError(
          "Please enter a valid mobile number"
        ),
        [`email_${data.key}`]: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Please enter a valid email")
      };
      return result;
    }, {})
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{}}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape(validationSchema)}
    >
      {({ handleSubmit, values, errors, handleChange }) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {formData.map((data, index) => (
              <div key={index} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                <button onClick={() => deleteForm(data.key)}>Delete</button>
                <input name={`name_${data.key}`} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input name={`company_${data.key}`} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input name={`mobile_no_${data.key}`} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input name={`email_${data.key}`} onChange={handleChange} />
              </div>
            ))}
            <button onClick={createForm} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
              Create Form
            </button>
            <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Submit
            </button>
            {errors && (
              <div>
                <div>ERRORS: {JSON.stringify(errors)}</div>
                <div>VALUES: {JSON.stringify(values)}</div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default AddContact;
```

Comment: I tried this way but when you create multiple forms, the same errors are shown everywhere

Comment: The `errors` is having details of the field as well so you have to conditionally show the error based on the field.